# Searching for Key Inside an Object Array and Filtering Data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a dataset structured as follows:

```
[
    {
        "id": 805,
        "name": "test",
        "Email": [
            {
                "Name": "name1",
                "Email": "test1@domain.com"
            },
            {
                "Name": "name2",
                "Email": "test2@domain.com"
            },
            ...
        ],
        "createdDate": "..."
    },
    {
        "id": 806,
        "name": "test",
        "Email": [
            {
                "Name": "name1",
                "Email": "test1@domain.com"
            },
            {
                "Name": "name2",
                "Email": "test2@domain.com"
            },
            ...
        ],
        "createdDate": "..."
    },
    ...
]
```

I'm filtering this data based on an array of selected IDs:

```
this.data = this.data.filter(item => this.selectedId.includes(item.id));
```

Where `this.selectedId` is an array containing IDs like `['805', '806']`.

Now, I also want to filter the data to include entries where the 'Email' array contains a specific email address, say `'test1@domain.com'`. I tried modifying the filter to include this condition:

```
this.data = this.data.filter(item =>
    this.selectedId.includes(item.id) || Object.keys(item.Email).includes(email)
);
```

However, the filtering doesn't seem to work as intended. I want to show data that matches the selected IDs or contains a particular email address within the 'Email' array. Could someone provide guidance on how to correctly structure this filtering condition in JavaScript?

Any help or suggestions on refining this filter logic would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on you question please?

Comment: @SelakaNanayakkara I have one email in the email variable i want to search for that also in Email array object if it is there we need that data, first condition is working `(item=> this.selectedId.includes(item.id))`

Comment: Try: `this.data.filter((item => this.selectedId.includes(item.id)) || item.Email.some(o => o.Email === email));`. If both conditions need to be true, use `&&` instead of `||`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getKeyByValue(object, value) {
  return Object.keys(object).find(key => object[key] === value);
}


const map = {"first" : "1", "second" : "2"};
console.log(getKeyByValue(map,"2"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect for the lambda expression/function.

While you can use the `.find()` with double negation (`!!`) to indicate the `Email` filter returns value.

```
this.data = this.data.filter(item => this.selectedId.includes(item.id)
    || !!item.Email.find(x => x.Email == this.email));
```

Or with `.findIndex()`

```
this.data = this.data.filter(item => this.selectedId.includes(item.id)
    || item.Email.findIndex(x => x.Email == this.email) > -1);
```

Note that with `selectedId = ['805','806']`, you will get the incompatible error as the `id`s provided in your `data` array are `Number`.